# Can some members of a class be accessible only by base classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, composite

I have a `Widget` class and a `CompositeWidget` that is derived from it. `CompositeWidget` adds child management behaviour. The `Widget` constructor takes a `CompositeWidget*` parameter as the widget parent. I need to use this parent pointer to access some functionality within the `CompositeWidget`. For example:

```
Widget::Widget(CompositeWidget* parent)
{
    parent_->AddChild(*this);
}
```

This forces me to create a public method `CompositeWidget::AddChild`. Is is possible to keep this interface private to the class hierarchy (a little like a reverse-`protected` access - limited to base classes)? Am I making a design faux pas in thinking about the problem like this?

**Edit:** I am trying to avoid friendship (if it's possible in this case).

Comment: Can you make `Widget` a friend of `CompositeWidget`?

Comment: And what about the top CompositeWidget? What pointer does it pass to it's base Widget c'tor? This seems like a poor design.

Comment: the GoF book Design Patterns has an extensive discussion on this in the section on Composite

Comment: @TemplateRex Regrettably, I don't own the book. Could you post an answer relaying some of the information in it?

Comment: @DanNestor: The Composite pattern can be found online too - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `friend` keyword.

```
class Widget { ... };

class CompositeWidget {
  friend class Widget;
};
```

However, you can alternatively insert the `virtual` method `AddChild` on the `Widget` class.

Answer (score 3):

> This forces me to create a public method

No, you could declare:

```
friend class Widget;
```

In the CompositeWidget declaration.  However...

> Am I making a design faux pas

Having a parent class method that references a derived class has a whiff of design flaw in it, perhaps, but I won't say it's categorically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your concrete question: declare `Widget` to be a `friend` of your `CompositeWidget` and make `AddChild` a `private` member.

Alternatively, move the child management to `CompositeWidget`. The [**Design Patterns**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) book has an extended discussion on this in their section on the [**Composite Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

> **The decision involves a trade-off between safety and transparency**:
>
> - Defining the child management interface **at the root of the class    hierarchy** gives you transparency, because you can treat all components uniformly. It costs you safety, however, because clients may try to do meaningless things like add and remove objects from leaves.
> - Defining child management **in the Composite class** gives you safety, because any attempt to add or remove objects from leaves will be caught at compile-time in a statically typed language like C++. But you lose transparency, because leaves and composites have different interfaces.
>
> We have emphasized transparency over safety in this pattern. If you
>   opt for safety, then at times you may lose type information and have
>   to convert a component into a composite. How can you do this without
>   resorting to a type-unsafe cast?

They go on to give a long code example, which essentially boils down to this design where the `CompositeWidget` contains the child management:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    //
    virtual Composite* GetComposite() { return 0; }
}

class CompositeWidget: public Widget
{
public:
    void AddChild(Component*); 
    // ...
    virtual Composite* GetComposite() { return this; }   
};

class LeafWidget: public Widget
{
     // no child management here
};
```

`GetComposite` lets you query a widget to see if it's a composite. You
can perform `AddChild` safely on the composite it returns.